# How to check if every certain elements exists

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I would like to know how to check if every certain elements exists.
I wrote the following code but I don't think that is smart.

```
if(xmlDoc.Descendants("ElementA").Any() && xmlDoc.Descendants("ElementB").Any() && ....
```

Comment: If you need to validate more than 3 elements I suggest to validate against the according Xsd schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
if (new[] {"ElementA", "ElementB", "ElementC"}
           .All(element => xmlDoc.Descendants(element).Any()))
{
}
```

And if you can, I suggest saving a member:

```
private static readonly string[] ELEMENTS = new string[]
                                                {
                                                    "ElementA",
                                                    "ElementB",
                                                    "ElementC"
                                                };
```

instead of recreating it everytime. Then you could do:

```
if (ELEMENTS.All(element => xmlDoc.Descendants(element).Any()))
{
}
```